# php find index where time difference is smallest compared with a date time array

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to find two indicies given two datetimes and an array of datetimes. I want to find the index of the respective two dates, where the time is closest to what is available in the datetime array. Here is what I tried:

```
$label = array();
$price = array();
$linePoints = array();

$ind = 0;
// format example $oT = '2018-05-05 12:05:55'
$checkOpen = strtotime($oT);
$checkClose = strtotime($cT);

while ($run = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
    $p = $run->price;
    $l = $run->time;
    array_push($price, $p);
    array_push($label, $l);

    // format example: $l = '2018-05-05 12:05:52' 

    $check = strtotime($l);

    $dif = abs($checkOpen - $check);
    if($dif < 10){
        array_push($linePoints, $ind);
    }

    $dif = abs($checkClose - $check);
    if($dif < 10){
        array_push($linePoints, $ind);
    }

    $ind = $ind +1;

}
```

The problem with this approach is, that this approach may bring multiple matches since the time difference is computed as milliseconds I guess? In the end, I only want two have two indicies in the array `$linePoints`. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For this job the DB is much faster than PHP. You'll gain simplicity and performance.

```
if($run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT event_id FROM Table ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( time, $checkOpen ) ) LIMIT 1")){
$price1 = $run->price;
$label1 = $run->label
}

if($run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT event_id FROM Table ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( time, $checkClose ) ) LIMIT 1")){
$price2 = $run->price;
$label2 = $run->label
}
```

Comment: thanks - makes sense to me. However, I specifically need the index, i.e. a number where the closest match exists. So if the closest time match between the $checkOpen and the label array is at the 5th element, I want to store 5 - can I use the DB for that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here you're, then. Your code is fixed now.

```
$label = array();
$price = array();
$linePoints = array();

$ind = 0;
// format example $oT = '2018-05-05 12:05:55'
$checkOpen = strtotime($oT);
$checkClose = strtotime($cT);

while ($run = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){

    $p = $run->price;
    $l = $run->time;
    array_push($price, $p);
    array_push($label, $l);

    // format example: $l = '2018-05-05 12:05:52' 

    $check = strtotime($l);

    $dif = abs($checkOpen - $check);
    if($dif < abs ($checkOpen - $linePoints[0]){
        $linePoints[0] = $ind);
    }

    $dif = abs($checkClose - $check);
    if($dif < $checkClose - $linePoints[1]){
        $linePoints[1] = $ind;
    }

    $ind = $ind +1;

}
```